# Android Navigation Drawer styling

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm using a Navigation Drawer in my app and I'm stuck. I was able to create the drawer and style the drawer items as I'd like. However, I can't figure out how to change the color of the "overlay" that appears to the right of the Drawer when it slides out (left to right). The current color is a dark gray. I want it to be white. I've been searching online for a few hours with no luck. I'm guessing this gray color is from the parent theme, but I don't know which item I need to customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [scrim color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setScrimColor(int)), you can change it like this:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(0x88FFFFFF);
```